# How many diagonal matrices that satisfy a $A^2 - 2A + E_3 = 0$?

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to solve this ,but it's proven impossible for me. I've done some work, but the answer I got is $1$, and I hightly doubt it's really that. If you could show me step by step how to do it, I'll really appreciate it.

```
A={a 0 0}      
   0 b 0
   0 0 c
```

A^2-2*A+E_3=

```
{a^2-2*a+1      0       0}
{    0     b^2-2*b+1    0}
{    0      0   c^2-2*c+1}
```

From there I find the roots of each quadratic equation , x=1 for all three. Since there is one option for a root, and three quadratic, I do : 
1*1*1=1^3 = 1

Comment: What is $E_3$?  Also, why do you doubt your answer?  Include it in the question so we can see.

Comment: By $E_3$, do you mean the identity matrix $I_3$?

Comment: Hey, didn't expect such fast responses. I'll try and put a picture of my answer so you can see what I did.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $E_3 =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, notice that $A^2 - 2A + E_3 = (A-E_3)^2$, so if $A = \begin{pmatrix} x & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & y & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & z \end{pmatrix}$ your equation becomes

$$\begin{pmatrix} x-1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & y-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & z-1 \end{pmatrix} ^2 = 0 .$$

But raising to the square is easy for diagonal matrices, and the above equation can be rewritten as

$$\begin{pmatrix} (x-1)^2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & (y-1)^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & (z-1)^2 \end{pmatrix} = 0 ,$$

whence it follows that $x=y=z=1$ and, indeed, there is a single solution to your equation, namely $A = E_3$.

(Keep in mind that if $M$ is a diagonal matrix having diagonal $x_1, \dots, x_n$ and if $N$ is a diagonal matrix having diagonal $y_1, \dots, y_n$, then $MN$ is a diagonal matrix having diagonal $x_1 y_1, \dots, x_n y_n$.)